# AngularJS: Overriding cellClass in Header

Tags: angularjs, ng-grid

If I apply a class of "text-right" to an ng-grid field, even the header cell is affected and looks weird. Does anyone know how to override this and have the class only affect the data?

Here's a [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/YaZoanXaeEGGUyunK0bf?p=preview)

main.js

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', ['ngGrid']);
app.controller('MyCtrl', function($scope) {

    $scope.heroes = [
    {
      id: 1,
      name: 'Iron Man',
      fname: 'Tony',
      lname: 'Stark',
      alias: 'Tony Stark',
      location: 'Stark Tower',
      comic: 'Marvel',
      intelligence: 99.6,
      strength: 85.0,
      speed: 57.9,
      durability: 85
    },
    {
      id: 2,
      name: 'Batman',
      fname: 'Bruce',
      lname: 'Wayne',
      alias: 'Bruce Wayne',
      location: 'Bat Cave',
      comic: 'DC',
      intelligence: 97.4,
      strength: 18,
      speed: 27.9,
      durability: 42
    },
    {
      id: 3,
      name: 'Superman',
      fname: 'Clark',
      lname: 'Kent',
      alias: 'Clark Kent',
      location: 'Metroplis',
      comic: 'DC',
      intelligence: 89.4,
      strength: 99.8,
      speed: 99.9,
      durability: 91.9
    },
    {
      id: 1,
      name: 'Daredevil',
      fname: 'Jack',
      lname: 'Murdock',
      alias: 'Jack Murdock',
      location: 'Court Room',
      comic: 'Marvel',
      intelligence: 75.4,
      strength: 13.8,
      speed: 27,
      durability: 28.3
    },
    {
      id: 5,
      name: 'Flash',
      fname: 'Barry',
      lname: 'Allen',
      alias: 'Barry Allen',
      location: 'Speedline',
      comic: 'DC',
      intelligence: 63,
      strength: 10,
      speed: 100,
      durability: 59.9
    },
    {
      id: 6,
      name: 'Hulk',
      fname: 'Bruce',
      lname: 'Banner',
      alias: 'Bruce Banner',
      location: 'Labratory',
      comic: 'Marvel',
      intelligence: 88,
      strength: 100,
      speed: 46.7,
      durability: 100
    },
    {
      id: 7,
      name: 'Hawkeye',
      fname: 'Clint',
      lname: 'Barton',
      alias: 'Clint Barton',
      location: 'Nest',
      comic: 'Marvel',
      intelligence: 56.7,
      strength: 12.8,
      speed: 23,
      durability: 14
    },
    {
      id: 8,
      name: 'Thor',
      fname: 'Donald',
      lname: 'Blake',
      alias: 'Donald Blake',
      location: 'Asgard',
      comic: 'Marvel',
      intelligence: 69.4,
      strength: 99.8,
      speed: 91.9,
      durability: 100
    }
  ];

    $scope.gridOptions = { 
        data: 'heroes',
        //showGroupPanel: true,
        enableRowSelection: false,
        enableCellEdit: true,
        columnDefs: [
          {field: 'name', displayName: 'Name', enableCellEdit: true},
          {field: 'alias', displayName: 'Alias'},
          {field: 'strength', displayName: 'Strength', cellFilter: 'number:1', cellClass: "text-right"},
          {field: 'comic', displayName: 'Comic'}
          ]
    };
});
```

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="myApp">
    <head lang="en">
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Custom Plunker</title>  
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="ng-grid.css" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css" />
        <script src="jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="angular.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="ng-grid.debug.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="main.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body ng-controller="MyCtrl">
        <div class="gridStyle" ng-grid="gridOptions"></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

style.css

```
.gridStyle {
    border: 1px solid rgb(212,212,212);
    width: 500px; 
    height: 300px
}

.text-right{
  text-align: right;
}
```

Comment: The plunker link doesn't seem to match this code. For example, style.css doesn't have .text-right

Comment: sorry, I guess I didn't save the plunker

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a more specific / tailored CSS selector:

```
.gridTextRight .ngViewport{
  text-align: right;
}
```

Otherwise, ensure that your `text-right` class is specifically applied to the content that you want aligned.

**Edit:** That said, it looks strange to me if just the data is aligned right (not the header cells). If you're just trying to keep other areas (grouping, etc.) left-aligned then you'll want to add a CSS selector for `gridTextRight .ngHeaderContainer` as well:

```
.gridTextRight .ngViewport, .gridTextRight .ngHeaderContainer{
  text-align: right;
}
```

Comment: I don't think the ng-grid API gives you the option to specifically apply classes ... I am trying your code now

Comment: no, it just left-aligned both the header and the data

Comment: If you're using the CSS I added, make sure you add the class `gridTextRight` to the grid.

Comment: actually once I get it working on Plunker, my real project requires all header cells centered and numbers right-aligned and text left-aligned ... just trying to affect them separately now

Comment: Maybe that is the crux of the issue ... I just downloaded ng-grid and am just starting to learn to use it and I don't understand how to apply classes other than through cellClass (in the API)... so, I wouldn't know how to add gridTextRight to the grid

Comment: You can add classes to the whole grid by just putting them on the DOM element in the HTML, same as all Angular directives. If you want the headers to be centred, then add a CSS rule targeting `ngHeaderContainer` and applying `text-align: center` to it.

Comment: http://plnkr.co/edit/ctfL2J4BYHkQzSYHidV0?p=preview should satisfy your requirements (centred headers, etc.)

Answer (score 2):

Here is your plunker with a cellTemplate that only affects the data and not the header:

http://plnkr.co/edit/ZHTSejyJuSrkiSnEEuj8?p=preview

the template:

```
   var myCellTemplate = "<div class='text-right'>{{row.getProperty(col.field)}}</div>";
```

and the template specification:

```
{field: 'strength', displayName: 'Strength', cellFilter: 'number:1', cellTemplate: myCellTemplate /*cellClass: "text-right"*/},
```

Comment: awesome ... I didn't understand cellTemplate in the API so I didn't consider it but that is really important and useful